# Why are the images displayed vertically rather than horizontally

Tags: html, css

Why are the images displayed vertically? I have two images within *figure* within *span* rather than div yet they are displayed one under another, I want them displayed beside each other if there is enough room, which there is.

```css
.largeartwork img {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="largeartwork">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/RhptaKqkpmMJ6w-Y7iJHqg==.jpg">
            <figcaption>
                Current Image
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="images/7xZ_CPneKuf6IRuYp4omnQ==.jpg">
            <figcaption>
                Current Image
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </span>
```

Comment: Because they are in figure elements - which are block elements

Comment: Also you html is invalid - figure is not allowed as a child of span

Comment: @Pete thx fixed title

Comment: why isnt figure allowed in span (and how do you know where would I check that)

Comment: [You can validate it here](https://validator.w3.org/).  Check the permitted tags [section here (phrasing content)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use display:flex

```
.largeartwork{
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Actually it works when i have width space, but when i viewed on my phone which doesnt have space I expected to be displayed vertically but still displayed horizontally

Comment: You can use "flex-wrap: wrap"
visit this page https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp

Comment: Thanks again that did it